# Calling methods in java and C#

Tags: java, c#

I have this code:

```
public class e{
  int k;
  int m;
  int c;

  public method(int a,int b,int c){

    k=a;
    m=b;
    c=c;

  }

}
```

Can we call a method in java or C# like this without parameters but separated with commas:

```
e object=new e();
object.method(,,);
```

Comment: I don't know about C#, but in Java you surely can't

Comment: If you wrote the class and want to do that, just define another `object.method` that takes no parameters and does the same things.

Comment: `Can we call a method in java or C# like this without parameters but separated with commas:` What do you *really* want to do? See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: why does it get downvoted? an interesting question for me. Maybe, you are looking for varargs, you could pass here 0,n arguments

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I suppose it's because people think it doesn't show research effort, is unclear, or is not useful.  After all, if it's just a question about syntax, the OP could have just dropped the code into a compiler to find out.  If it's meant to be more conceptual, the OP should have included what they were trying to accomplish in their question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we call a method in java or C# like this without parameters but
>   separated with commas:

No you can't. According to the method's signature there are expected 3 integer literals. That being said, you can't call it this way.

Regarding the C#, you could define `a`, `b` and `c` as optional int, like below:

```
public void Method(int a = 0, int b = 3, int c = 2)
{
    // ...
}
```

and call the method as below:

```
object.Method()
```

or as:

```
object.Method(1);
```

etc. Regarding this feature, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In C# as many other languages, a method can have *parameters*. If it has parameters, you must provide them.

If you've in mind something like giving zero or endless arguments to a given method, C# has it since its inception:

```
public class A
{
  public void Method(params object[] args)
  {

  }
}

A a = new A();
// You can give infinite arguments and they'll be received as indexes
// of the "args" array
a.Method(1, "hello world", true);
```

Otherwise, calling a method with just commas is pointless and it has no goal in C# world, thus, it's not supported.